# Using Lottie files with LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, lottie

I am trying to use Lottie files with my libGDX game.
I downloaded the files from https://www.lottiefiles.com/
which are downloaded in JSON format but I am unable to figure out or find any tutorial on how to use them.

Is it not possible to use Lottie with libGDX. if not, is there a good animation library like Lottie which can be used with libGDX?

**Edits:**

It's not just about Lottie, it appears to me that the only was to add animation to libGdx is to use the TexturePacker to pack a set of images into a sprite sheet. Is it not possible to use a pre-made json format textureAtlas for animation?
Currently I am trying to export an animation from Adobe Animate CC as a texture atlas but I can't find anything on how to use it in LibGdx.

Comment: Sorry, LibGDX doesn't support Lottie files

Comment: May be [Tween engine](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Universal-Tween-Engine) or [spine](http://esotericsoftware.com/spine-in-depth) can be helpful for your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for this info :). have added more details in the question.